# Google charts save zoomed image as PNG

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, png

I'm using Google Charts to create a line chart, and I'm using

```
explorer: {actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
```

to allow the user to zoom in on a bounding box. I'd like to be able to save the zoomed image as a PNG. To do so, I'm trying to find the HAxis values at the left and right edges of the chart and the VAxis values at the top and bottom edges of the chart:

```
var cli = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
var hl = cli.getHAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().left);
var hr = cli.getHAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().left + cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().width);
var vt = cli.getVAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().top);
var vb = ??
```

Then I'm using these in my options to replot the chart with these limits:

```
var options = {
    width: 1430,
    height: 563,
    hAxis: {
        title: 'X-Axis',
        viewWindow: { min: hl, max: hr}
    },
    explorer: {actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], keepInBounds: true, maxZoomIn: .01 },
    curveType: "function",
    vAxis: {
        logScale: log1, 
        title: "Y-Axis", 
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#0000FF'}, 
        textStyle: {color: '#0000FF'}, 
        baselineColor: '#0000FF', 
        viewWindow: { min: vb, max: vt}}
    },
    title: "Figure 1"
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('plot'));
chart.draw(data, options);
drawpng = chart.getImageURI();
return drawpng;
```

My values for the left, right, and top edges are working correctly, but I can't figure out how to determine the bottom edge. I've already tried

```
var vb = cli.getVAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().top - cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().height)
```

and

```
var vb = cli.getVAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().height)
```

and

```
var vb = cli.getVAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().height - cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().top)
```

but none of these are giving me the correct value.

Does anyone know how to make this work, or another way of saving the zoomed in chart?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using

```
cli.getVAxisValue(cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().top+cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox().height)
```

I hadn't realized that the position was being calculated from the top, not the bottom.